# Filtering based on belongsTo relation in loopback

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

I would like to filter a model, based on its parent `belongsTo` relation.

For example, I have a `Customer` model and a `Books` model.

A `Customer hasMany Books` and a `Book belongsTo Customer`, with each table potentially being quite huge.

I'd like to get a list of unique books, where the owning `Customer` has a name of `John`.

So far, I know I can go from the Book model with a query that looks something like:

```
Book.find({
    include: {
        relation: 'customer',
        scope: {
            where: {name: 'John'}
        }
    }
}, function(err, books) {
    // Loop through the books here
});
```

Or I could approach it from the Customer model, and manually merge the book lists (removing duplicates):

```
Customer.find({
    where: {name: 'John'}
}, function(err, customers) {
    var books = customers.map(customer => customer.books);
    // Remove duplicates here
});
```

I would prefer the first approach, since it seems like it would do the duplication logic on the querying side.

However, that approach seems to include *all* books, but only for the ones where the customer name is *John* does it add on the `customer` attribute.

Am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: This is sadly not fully implemented yet. You can track progress in [this](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/517) github issue.

Comment: Yeah after some further research I realized that loopback has not yet implemented inner joins yet, so will have to do it manually for now.